# Image doesn't show up openGL

Tags: c, image, opengl, display, soil

I'm trying to display image with OpenGL and SOIL, but I couldn't make it.When I call this function, only empty square appears.

```
   void display_image(char* file_name)
{
    GLuint texture_id=loadIm(file_name);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
glLoadIdentity();
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0); glVertex3f(0, 0.0, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(width, 0.0, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0); glVertex3f(width, height, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(0,height, 0.0);
glEnd();
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();    
}
```

If you want to check loadIm func here it is:

```
GLuint loadIm(char *file_name)
{
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GLuint texture_id;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
width,height;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

    unsigned char *image = SOIL_load_image(file_name, &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

    SOIL_free_image_data(image);

    if (texture_id == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return texture_id;

}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: (1) Try setting the color to all 1-s; (2) Ensure that `GL_CULL_FACE` is disabled and `glFrontFace​()` is set to `GL_CCW`; (3) OpenGL 1.1 in 2016, seriously?

Comment: @hidefromkgb thanks for answer.Only square's line's color has changed, its blue black and white now.  And by the way, I had no time to investigate graphic libraries, and I'm about the finish my project, opening image file is the last part.

Comment: Lines, you say? Well, then you most probably need [`glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml).

Comment: its recommend to use shaders, there is point do develop new software in the old glBegin() .. glEnd() style from pre 2003.

Comment: @hidefromkgb Yes I meant lines. I just tried to open blue triangle image, and this is output:

[link](http://oi64.tinypic.com/wi362p.jpg)

Thank you anyway, It's better than have nothing.